# Why are vector spaces defined over a field?

Tags: vector-spaces, definition, convention

I have a general intuition of what vectors are/look like in the context of physics and what not. But it doesn't seem too closely related to properties of a field. So why are they defined over a field and not some arbitrary ring or something. Might be missing something...

Comment: Modules are the name for a "vector space over a ring".

Comment: The fact that the scalars form a field makes vector spaces extremely well behaved in a number of ways. For instance, in a vector space $V$ over a field $k$, if $V$ has a basis of size $n$ then *any* linearly independent set of size $n$ spans all of $V$. But this fails for modules (= vector spaces over rings): e.g. if we consider $\mathbb{Z}$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, then it has a one-element basis $\{1\}$, and $\{2\}$ is linearly independent but does not span.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They *are* defined over general rings, *but* vector spaces all have a basis, while modules need not have one. Modules which have a basis are known as `free` modules (`of finite type`  if they have a finite basis).

Worse, if the ring is not commutative, it may happen a free module has bases with different cardinalities.

Most modules have no basis. The simplest example would be the ideal $(X,Y)\subset K[X,Y]$ $\;K$ a field), which has $\{X,Y\}$ as a minimal set of generators, but they're not linearly independent since $\;Y\cdot X-X\cdot Y=0$.